# Check if specific paragraphs starts on a new page VBA WORD

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

The macro below searches in the active Word document paragrpahs containing specific text found in the array main_paragraphs and checks if the paragraph contianing the text starts on a new page.
This works but it is VERY VERY slow...
Is there another way to write the code for this or any thoughts how I could optimise this to make it faster?

```
Sub Tidy_Pages()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim current_paragraph_descriptor
    Dim current_seach_string As String
    Dim ParagraphRange As Object
    
    main_paragraphs = Array("Br - Decision", "Nu - Decision", "Co - Decision", "Sk -  Decision", "Mo  - Decision", "Com - Decision", "Psy - Decision", "Cog - Decision", "Beh - Decision", "Med - Decision", "ASC - Decision", "Oth - Decision")
    
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
         Set ParagraphRange = para.Range
         For Each current_paragraph_descriptor In main_paragraphs
               ParagraphRange.Find.Text = current_paragraph_descriptor
               ParagraphRange.Find.Execute
               If ParagraphRange.Find.Found Then
                    If para.PageBreakBefore = False Then para.PageBreakBefore = True
               End If
         Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Optimise running time

Comment: This looks like an XY problem.  Can you take a step back and explain why you are trying the code above.  The fact that you are checking for pagebreakbefore implies your document is badly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through the keyword array and searching in the entire document is a more efficient approach than looping through each paragraph individually.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Tidy_Pages()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim current_paragraph_descriptor, main_paragraphs
    main_paragraphs = Array("Br - Decision", "Nu - Decision", "Co - Decision", "Sk -  Decision", "Mo  - Decision", "Com - Decision", "Psy - Decision", "Cog - Decision", "Beh - Decision", "Med - Decision", "ASC - Decision", "Oth - Decision")
    For Each current_paragraph_descriptor In main_paragraphs
        Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
        With rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = current_paragraph_descriptor
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Forward = True
        End With
        Do While rng.Find.Execute
            Set para = rng.Paragraphs(1)
            If Not para.PageBreakBefore Then
                para.PageBreakBefore = True
            End If
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `Find` method but do a text compare via `LIKE` plus `Exit For` in case a match was found:

```vb
Sub Tidy_Pages()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim current_paragraph_descriptor
    Dim current_seach_string As String
    Dim ParagraphRange As Object
    
    Dim main_paragraphs As Variant
    main_paragraphs = Array("Br - Decision", "Nu - Decision", "Co - Decision", "Sk -  Decision", "Mo  - Decision", "Com - Decision", "Psy - Decision", "Cog - Decision", "Beh - Decision", "Med - Decision", "ASC - Decision", "Oth - Decision")
    
    Dim strTemp As String
    
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If para.PageBreakBefore = False Then
            strTemp = para.Range.Text
             For Each current_paragraph_descriptor In main_paragraphs
                If strTemp Like "*" & current_paragraph_descriptor & "*" Then
                     para.PageBreakBefore = True
                     Exit For
                 End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That still involves exactly the same steps. Its looping through the paragraphs and then using Find that makes it slow. The best approach is to use Find to get to the paragraphs, as in the answer from Taller.

Comment: Yes - but usually a pure string compare is faster than `find` plus `exit for` in case of success plus only checking para w/o pagebreakbefore